# setValue not moving UISlider

Tags: swift, xcode, uislider

i have added a slider to my storyboard and connected it. the result is this code inside my "Viewcontroller.swift":

```
@IBOutlet var control1: UISlider!
```

[image]

when i try to change the value with this command:

```
control1.setValue(resultAvPitch, animated: false)
```

the app is crashing:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value 2020-02-15 13:55:54.045989+0100 UIGrid[8695:898849] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) –

i found somewhere a small code snippet and put it above this function:

```
let control1 = UISlider()
```

like that its not crashing anymore but it doesnt make the slider move.. what am i doing wrong?. is there an option that i need to click somewhere in the storyboard?

note: i placed the slider inside a view and another view like that:

[image]

Comment: "the app is crashing:": Show the error message when this happens.

Comment: here we go.. thats without the "let-constant" :resultAvPitch : 6129.1567
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
2020-02-15 13:55:54.045989+0100 UIGrid[8695:898849] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: I suspected it. Did you link the IBOutlet Code declaration into the Interface?

Comment: i did. i have added the slider in the storyboard and linked it with the "viewcontroller.swift". its working when i change the slider i get values from it. this code (like shown above) is the result of dragging it into the script: @IBOutlet var control1: UISlider!

Answer (score 0):

what helped in the end was removing all sliders, drag and connect them again. i have checked muliple times what the differences were but i didnt find anything.